# htaccess delete characters from url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to strip `_/` from url.

Example: `mysite.com/_/something` want to redirect to `mysite.com/something`

Comment: I want to see what you've tried.

Comment: I was thinking something like this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)[_/](.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com/%1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^_/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: when i add `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` turns to page error 500

Comment: Read the error in `error.log`? Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: This is properly tested and working code. You need to be able to look into Apache error log file to see why you're getting 500. My suspicion is either mod_rewrite OP .htaccess is not enabled through httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to do a redirect correct?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/_/$ http://mysite.com/something
```

If you have Go Daddy hosting then you would have to do this:

/wordpress-testing-website/ is the folder where this testing site exists. The post name is "test_" in this example

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wordpress-testing-website/(.*)_/$ http://www.ait-pro.com/wordpress-testing-website/uncategorized/something/
```