# mod_rewrite to remove underscores from URLS

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has old URLs such as /news/story/MasterCard_-Accounts-Don_t-Need-To-Own-Accounts-Until-Volume-Hits-_maximum

That need to be /news/story/MasterCard-Accounts-Dont-Need-To-Own-Accounts-Until-Volume-Hits-maximum

The URLs are from a previous site version that turned special characters into underscores.  The new site just omits the underscores which are causing 404s on any indexed and internal links

So basically, I'm looking to have them rewritten without the underscores.  Everything I am finding only shows how to change them to another character such as a dash but that won't suit my requirement.  Can they simply be scrubbed away?  I can do this via htaccess or using a regex in the redirection plugin.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am banging my head on my desk at this point.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189363/htaccess-delete-characters-from-url-and-redirect) may help you find an appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive set of rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1$2 [N,DPI]
```

Comment: Comment here in case you run into any issue.